# AngularJS - json data from view to controller

Tags: javascript, json, xslt, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I get my html template + json data from xsl translator , it is dynamic , it looks like html code plus some data in stringified json. The question is: in what way i put the json string in html code , so that  controller will catch this json data before html rendering? When i simple put it like this:

```
<div>{{ $scope.categories = [{},{},...]}}</div>
<div ng-repeat="category in categories" class="category">...</div>
```

it works good , but brings some strange error:

```
Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

So what is the good way to pass data from view to controller?

Comment: Can you show how you get JSON data? Do you use [`$http`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http)?

Comment: @the_lay like this: `$routeProvider.when('/categories', { templateUrl: 'retrieve_xml.php?Xsl=categories.xsl', controller: 'CategoriesCtrl'
})`

Comment: Can you show `CategoriesCtrl`?  What is `<div>{{ $scope.categories = [{},{},...]}}</div>` for?

Comment: @sh0ber CategoriesCtrl is still empty function . i want to pass it some data after the template is loaded.

Comment: @Cherniv I can suggest you make it a little bit another way: in controller put `$http.get(retrieve_xml.php?Xsl=categories.xsl).success(function (result) { $scope.categories = result; }`. This way categories variable will have all the data it got from your .xml file and then it can properly render html.

Comment: @Cherniv oh and in `$routeProvider` in `templateUrl` put your html partial view file, not the file you want to get.

Comment: @the_lay thank you for suggestion. i thought about the way you noted but i want to make it in one call to server. may be there is some way to catch data that route getting from server and parse it before the view is rendered?