# 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! - isolated scope

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting this error only when I have {{i}} set in hour or day attribute, someone could explain this behavior,please.

```
<td cell ng-repeat="j in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]" hour="i" day="j"></td>
```

And this is my directive :

```
app.directive('cell', function(){
    return {
      scope : {
        "day":"=",
        "hour":"="
      },
  controller: WeekCtrl,
  link: function(scope,elm,attrs){

    // When using isolated scope and if we want to include parent scope variables we should define the controller. (I'm ok?)
    // When outside , in the element, we define day="{{i}}" an error about $digest overflow is produced, but with day="i" nothing happens

  }
}
```

});

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376879/error-10-digest-iterations-reached-aborting-with-dynamic-sortby-predicate?rq=1

The response is interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you modifying your data while passing on it , here : `j in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`. Try something like

```
<td cell ng-repeat="j in myArr=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]" hour="i" day="j">
   <!--  myArr[j] = {{ myArr[j] }} -->
</td>
```

I had same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708053/angularjs-json-data-from-view-to-controller).