# AngularJS - Getting data inserted in dom

Tags: javascript, xml, angularjs, client-server, client-side

I'm looking for a way to get initial data from a DOM after the application is loaded. Data has been inserted in a view by a server. Is `Module`'s `value` method is a good way?

As well i want to know how to get data from a views when i'm working with `routes` , can i use `script` tags for injecting a data in specific scopes?

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086823/initial-data-loading-in-angularjs) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708053/angularjs-json-data-from-view-to-controller) questions but it didn't help a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [initial data loading in angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086823/initial-data-loading-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1) First solution inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015523/angular-js-is-value-the-proper-way-to-set-app-wide-constant-and-how-to-retri) and it is [`Module`'s `value` method](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.Module#value):

```
<script>
   var users_json = '[{"name":"Piotr"},{"name":"Natasha"}]'; // created by xsl
   myApp.value("PrimaryData" , users_json );
</script>
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="user in users">{{user.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Then we can use this `PrimaryData` when and where we wish , like this:

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, PrimaryData) {
    $scope.data = angular.copy(PrimaryData); 
    console.log( $scope.data[0].name === "John" );
});
```

But this way somehow not worked for me when i started to use `routes` , may be because the `value` only runs while application initialization.

2) So here comes the second solution: directives. Now when server sends a route's template , it puts inside some `script` tag with a `"text/template"` type and special directive name property and a json data in that tag,   like this:

```
<script  type = "text/template" rawdata >     <!-- "rawdata" is our directive
   '[{"name":"Nelson"},{"name":"Luis"}]'      // created by xsl
</script>
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="user in users">{{user.name}}</li>    // view is beside
</ul>
```

And this directive catching it and passes the data to the current route' scope:

```
studio.directive('rawdata', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) { 
        if(scope.passRawData){
            var data = (element[0].innerHTML);
            scope.passRawData(data); // Or simply scope.users = JSON.parse(data)
        } else {
            console.log( "Scope has no passRawData method" );
        }
    }
  }
});
```

Awesome! :)

Comment: I just used the directive solution and it's great thanks.  But I had to remove the single quotes around the JSON in the script tag.  What made you put them there?